# Firebase/Google Cloud projects verification has no answer

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-oauth, verification

I have several projects on Firebase and sent them to OAuth verification via Google Cloud. Some of them were sent on Oct/Nov 2023. No reply emails were sent back to me. I acknowledged that they have estimated the time for the review of the project 4-6 weeks. But they also said that first reply will be in 7 days. For now, 10 projects have no answer for more than 5-6 months. Does anyone know how to get a reply or verification process to be started?

I've tried to resend them for review by getting them back to testing and after this to production. Still no reply from them after 4-6 weeks. Some over projects were verified.

Answer (score 1):

You need to file a [support case](https://console.cloud.google.com/support?_ga=2.205422355.-227890329.1709565262&_gac=1.88376809.1709575232.CjwKCAiA_5WvBhBAEiwAZtCU78qNMBDvnKgq_cThYeddVLGJ6rMZ3y0aZoeZDUPYrIe06iO9SA5AtxoC_xYQAvD_BwE) with Google Cloud so that they can check your account and review your pending OAuth verifications.

Comment: But I have Basic Support that provides me with documentation and community support. Or even with this I can file a support case?

Comment: It will be ideal for you to get in touch with the Trust & Safety team through the [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) page. So that they can check and verify the progress of your OAuth verification requests.

You can also review posts in the [help community](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/No-Email-Received-from-Google-Trust-and-Safety-Team-for-OAuth/td-p/600747) where they discuss similar issues like yours.

Comment: I'm kindly thankful for your help, but I have had no luck with their support team. Had a chat with their bot that still insists that I need to buy a subscription for their tech support. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place? I'm sorry for asking this, but can you please clarify how I can get a chat with their support team and not a bot while I'm on the basic support plan? Maybe some kind of instruction?